# Permission denied for gitweb.cgi on CentOS

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, git, selinux, cgi

I've set up gitweb on my web server. I have created projects on the server. I can add commits to them and also clone them remotely.

The gitweb "homepage" does display and the static files like css, logo, favicon are loaded when I visit my git.website.

Issue is I only see the message:  *No such projects found* found..
Every time I refresh the webpage I see the following in my /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Wed Aug 04 00:39:32.321352 2021] [cgid:error] [pid 44346:tid 140132795492096] [client MY_HOME_IP:37700] fatal: mmap failed: Permission denied: /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi, referer: https://git.mydomain.abc/
```

I've confirmed httpd is running as the apache user and have the ownership of /var/www set to apache as well. The permissions are properly set up as well I believe:

```
[root@git ~]# ps auxw | grep httpd
root       44780  0.2  1.6 281804 13828 ?        Ss   00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     44782  0.0  1.0 295684  8876 ?        S    00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     44783  0.0  1.7 1484604 14712 ?       Sl   00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     44784  0.0  2.2 1353476 18956 ?       Sl   00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     44785  0.0  2.0 1353476 16760 ?       Sl   00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     45019  0.0  1.7 1353476 14708 ?       Sl   00:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root       45141  0.0  0.1 221928  1140 pts/0    S+   00:48   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
[root@git ~]# ls -ld /var/ /var/www/ /var/www/git/ ; ls -lZ /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi 
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root   root   4096 Aug  2 18:16 /var/
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache   44 Aug  2 18:23 /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x.  8 apache apache  179 Aug  4 00:18 /var/www/git/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache system_u:object_r:git_script_exec_t:s0 253816 Jul 20  2020 /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi
[root@git ~]#
```

**/etc/gitweb.conf**

```
$projectroot = '/var/www/git/';
$git_temp = "/tmp";
$stylesheet = "static/gitweb.css";
$logo = "static/git-logo.png";
$favicon = "static/git-favicon.png";
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitweb-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName git.mydomain.abc 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/git
    <Directory /var/www/git>
        SetEnv  GITWEB_CONFIG  /etc/gitweb.conf
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>
    <Files gitweb.cgi>
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </Files>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.mydomain.abc/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.mydomain.abc/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If anybody sees what I've done wrong I'll very much appreciate some guidance.. Thanks!

**EDIT1:**
And here is the audit.log

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1628072069.412:134): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=no exit=-13 a0=0 a1=b9 a2=1 a3=2 items=0 ppid=2911 pid=2917 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="git" exe="/usr/bin/git" subj=system_u:system_r:git_script_t:s0 key=(null)ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=mmap AUID="unset" UID="apache" GID="apache" EUID="apache" SUID="apache" FSUID="apache" EGID="apache" SGID="apache" FSGID="apache"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1628072069.412:134): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F676974002D2D6769742D6469723D2F7661722F7777772F6769742F2F796F75747562652D646C2D62617463682E67697400666F722D656163682D726566002D2D666F726D61743D2528636F6D6D697474657229002D2D736F72743D2D636F6D6D697474657264617465002D2D636F756E743D3100726566
type=AVC msg=audit(1628072069.433:135): avc:  denied  { map } for  pid=2919 comm="git" path="/var/www/git/myrepo01.git/objects/1c/1c5ca1a07da5187a696cd1661d6b2a734ad98c" dev="vda1" ino=36639 scontext=system_u:system_r:git_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:git_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

**EDIT2**
The issue boils down to SELinux which I am not an expert in. Changing the mode to *Permissive* I can now see all my repos..
However I have to figure out how to make it work with *Enforced* mode..

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: Hi Michael, I did check the audit log and it again points to a "denied" message.. from what I can see the persmissions are there but when trying to access my git repos it fails, I added it to the main post.

Comment: It seems to be SELinux preventing it but am still trying to figure out what options exactly I have to amend to allow the cgi script to be executed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so something I didn't know about were the audit2why and audit2allow commands..
After narrowing down the issues as per *EDIT2* to SELinux, and passing the log over to audit2why it updated me that:

```
The boolean domain_can_mmap_files was set incorrectly.
```

and I have to:

```
Allow access by executing:
# setsebool -P domain_can_mmap_files 1
```

Ref: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=71917

This has now been resolved.
Thanks